# Does it make sense to start a new thread in the root of a message handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

This should be a quick one...

I have taken over development of a project from someone else and it seems to me that they haven't got a clue what they were doing. I have found numerous examples of bad code practices and logical errors that I'm sure would make your blood boil as much as mine. I am now dealing with an area of code in which they have for some unknown reason decided to create an absurd amount of message handlers. I think they don't understand what a handler is for... I have one class which contains as much as 4 handlers as class fields all created by the same thread! One of those handlers looks like this:

```
private Handler messageHandler1 = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        new Thread() { // why are we starting a thread in the root of a message handler?!
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                    // some code...
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

Besides the useless variable name, I'm more concerned by the creation of a new thread right at the root of the handler. My understanding of handlers is that they are used to allow you run code on another thread, so one thread can use the handler of another thread to be able to run code on that other thread... So then, surely it is totally pointless to use a handler in the first place if you're just going to create a new thread straight away?! I just wanted someone with a bit more wisdom to confirm that (or not) before I remove this handler and do it (what I believe to be) the right way.

Thanks

Comment: it depends, if all the `Message`s are to be handled in parallel you need a new `Thread` here (or any other way of async execution like `ExecutorService`), if they are to be handled sequentially in the background `Thread` just use `HandlerThread`

Comment: Without knowing anything about your software, it's hard to tell why it was done this way, but creating threads like this is certainly not a good sign. If the software needs to run asynchronous jobs, then at least use a thread pool, in the form of an `ExecutorService`. The `super.run();` call in that anonymous subclass of `Thread` is also unnecessary.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of it that way, so in general this could be okay but (get this)... This handler is actually only used once in the entire project. It is a one-time call that happens during the activation process for the application. So the concept of handling multiple messages in parallel is not relevant here. So I think this is definitely just another sign of my predecessor being totally clueless! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

A `Handler` is always pointing toward a `Thread`.
When the Handler receives a Message the best practice is that **Handler handles a message on its own Thread.** That is the whole point of creating a Handler in the first place.

Starting a new Thread from a within `Handler.handleMessage()` is a weird choice at best.